# SQL Return 2 Row From 1

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

I am not sure if this is possible or possible efficiently, but here is what I would like to do.

I have a table with the following columns: Date and Value

```
Date                  Value
06/09/2022 11:30PM    110
06/10/2022 12:45AM    100
06/10/2022 1:30AM     300
```

I want to do a select query that when a value spans 2 days between 12:00 AM and 12:59AM it returns 2 data points (Does not modify the underlying data) where the value each day is weighted by how much into the hour the timestamp that falls into this window is.

So in this case I would like my query to return:

```
Date                  Value
06/09/2022 11:30PM    110
06/09/2022 11:59PM    25
06/10/2022 12:59AM    75
06/10/2022 1:30AM     300
```

The questions I have are:

1. Is it possible to write a function or use SQL statements to return 2 rows from 1 without modifying the underlying data?
2. Is there a way to achieve this withing Postgres vs. in application?

Thanks

Comment: Hi - it's not clear, to me, what you mean. You have rows which each  show a single point in time so what do you mean by "spanning 2 days" - a single point in time has no duration?

Comment: If the data falls into 12:00 AM and 12:59 AM I would like to effectively split that row into two rows where a portion of the value is allotted to each day depending on how far the timestamp is between 12:00AM and 12:59AM

Comment: 40 minutes are 2/3 of an hour, so why should the two rows get 25 and 75 and not 33 and 67? At 12:30, they would get 50 and 50?

Comment: @JonasMetzler - typo forgot the 5

Comment: "If the data falls into 12:00 AM and 12:59 AM" - these times don't exist, did you mean 12:00PM or did you mean 00:00 AM? In any case both these times (if they did exist) would be in the same day so they can't be spanning 2 days. And to go back to my original comment - your data is showing that each record is for a single point in time so they have no duration and therefore your question and comments make no sense without further explanation for how you expect a row that has, for example, a single date of "06/09/2022 11:30PM" to span any period of time

Comment: @NickW - I simplified the problem to focus on the pertinent portions, but for some background the value is an hourly average. This is why I am looking to split a certain amount between a date line. Note the end goal is to have this be a generic psql function, but again not sure that is possible. The times are correct based on the intent of the question.

Comment: are you sure you want a function and not a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get more rows from table is to concatenate several results using union:

```
create table d (date timestamp, value float);
insert into d values ('2022/06/09 11:30PM',110),('2022/06/10 12:45AM',100),('2022/06/10 1:30AM',300);

select date as "Date", value as "Value" from d where date::time >= '1:00' 
union all
select date_trunc('day',date)+'0:59',
    value * extract (epoch from date::time)/3600
    from d where date::time < '1:00' 
union all
select date_trunc('day',date)-'0:01'::interval,
     value * (3600-extract (epoch from date::time))/3600
     from d where date::time < '1:00'
order by 1;
```

result:

```
        Date         | Value 
---------------------+-------
 2022-06-09 23:30:00 |   110
 2022-06-09 23:59:00 |    25
 2022-06-10 00:59:00 |    75
 2022-06-10 01:30:00 |   300
```

But you want this as a function?  I could use proceureal code here, but I already have it as a query, so I'll just use that.

```
create function mangle(inout "Date" timestamp,inout "Value" float)
  returns setof record language sql as $$
    select "Date", "Value" where "Date"::time >= '1:00' 
    union all
    select date_trunc('day',"Date")+'0:59',
        "Value" * extract (epoch from "Date"::time)/3600
        where "Date"::time < '1:00' 
    union all
    select date_trunc('day',"Date")-'0:01'::interval,
         "Value" * (3600-extract (epoch from "Date"::time))/3600
         where "Date"::time < '1:00'
    order by 1;
$$;

select (mangle(date,value)).* from d;
```

As you can see mixed-case identifiers get messy fast, so I reccomend you stick to lower case, unless you absolutely need them.

Comment: make sense to just use a union without worrying about it being a fcn. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provided you never see an entry on 23:59 on a day before an entry in the midnight hour, break it down as follows:

Find values to be split and figure out the share:

```
with to_be_split as (
  select date, value, 
         extract(minute from date)/60 as today_share,
         (60 - extract(minute from date))/60 as yesterday_share 
    from my_table
   where extract(hour from date) = 0
),
```

Do a lateral cross join into a `values` pseudo-table to create the extra rows:

```
splits as (
  select sub.date, round(tbs.value * sub.share) as value
    from to_be_split tbs
         cross join lateral (
           values (date, today_share),
                  (date_trunc('day', date) - interval '1 minute', yesterday_share)
         ) as sub(date, share)
)
```

Union the result back with records that don't need splitting:

```
select date, value
  from splits
union all
select date, value
  from my_table
 where extract(hour from date) != 0
 order by date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=79055739839eee367e58db12173ead0f)*